# Always 1 degree of freedom for hierarchical tests?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio

I'm trying to use the function lrtest() in r for two glm()-models. I want to do a hierarchical test for those two glm()-models, so that one of the glm()-models include all the variables and in the other glm()-model I've excluded just one of the variables.

I thought this meant that the Chi-squared statistic will have just 1 degree of freedom. But lrtest() in R says 1 sometimes and sometimes other numbers, I've seen 2 and 3 so far.

Have I got the theory all wrong or is lrtest() not doing what I think it is?

Comment: the degrees of freedom is the difference in parameters between the two models, so I suppose your full model includes either 3 or 4 coefficients?

Comment: @Mark Verhagen - Thank you for answering. I have 13 variables in my full model, and I only exclude one at a time and then use lrtest() to compare.

Comment: ah sorry, I misread your initial question. In some cases it might happen that complicated multilevel models drop certain fixed effects due to for example collinearity.. Have you checked the `summary` function on the models you are comparing to verify that indeed only one fixed effect is 'less'? It might also be that you are excluding both a fixed effect and a random slope?

Comment: @Mark Verhagen - I've checked for multicollinearity but all VIFs are 2 or less. Couold you explain a bit more what you wrote (I quote): 
"Have you checked the summary function on the models you are comparing to verify that indeed only one fixed effect is 'less'? It might also be that you are excluding both a fixed effect and a random slope?"

Comment: So I suspect your LR test will be something of the form `lr_test(m1, m2)` correct? I would just advise having a look at `summary(m1)` and `summary(m2)` to double check there isn't something going on in estimating, specifically some additional fixed effects dropping out of the model. Note also that it could be that if some of the effects you are dropping are categorical, your estimation sequence actually turns these into separate regressors which could explain why you sometimes get 3 degrees of freedom (which would happen if you dropped a 4-level categorical if you include an intercept)